# игнорируется нажатие после открытия кавычек в phpstorm

Tags: ide, macos, phpstorm

после того как в шторме открываю кавычку, следующее нажатие игнорируется и только второе нажатие срабатывает. Например нажимаю <kbd>'</kbd>, потом <kbd>ф</kbd>, потом <kbd>ы</kbd>. В итоге получим <kbd>'ы</kbd>.

phpStorm 10
macOs 10.11

Comment: Попробуйте создать свой снипет на символ кавычки

Comment: Проблема была в маке. А точнее в раскладке. В настройках клавиатуры выбрал источник ввода "США" вместо "США международная ПК" и проблема исчезла.